# What is the best way to detect smaller devices like mobiles or tablets in CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media, tablet

When i read about responsive design, people always seam to use this statement:
@media screen and(max-width: )

But mobile phones today seem to have really great resolution (often more than pc), whats the best way to detect small devices?

Thx ;=)

Comment: what do you mean "smaller"? by pixels or by physical size? My ~4" galaxy nexus has more pixels than a 10" ipad 2...

Comment: Yes physical, this is actually the problem. You cant detect size of device by resolution

Comment: theoretically you should be able to use real-world units like you would in css. `12in` or `5cm`. never tried it, though. The CSS rendering engine should handle the necessary work of getting the device's screen specs and DPI ratings and convert those realworld units to physical pixel measurements

Comment: In css 1in is always 96px (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screen resolution does not matter. The value used in media queries is the **device width**. For example:

My phone has a screen with a resolution of 1280x720 pixels. When held upright (in portrait mode) the width is 720px, but since it is an HD screen, it has a 200% ratio, and the resulting device width is 360px. This is the value used in media queries:

```
/* Even though my phone has a screen width of 720px… */

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
     /* 
      * This code will apply 
      */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 361px) {
     /* 
      * This code will not apply
      */
}
```

The general rule is that phones in portrait mode have a device width less or equal to 400px, regardless of how many actual pixels their screen contains.

Comment: Trying on Sony Xperia Z1 Compact with a threshold of 400px. Don't work's (Chrome browser on the Xperia shows the same like on a desktop browser). Really no other solution to detect small screen devices?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.normal.css" media="(min-width: 400px)" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.mobile.css" media="(max-width: 400px)" />` This loads on the Xperia the *normal.css". I must set the width threshold at least to 980 pixel to load on the Xperia the mobile.css.

Comment: @Steffen Hm, I’m not sure what browser support is like for the `media` attribute. I use a single style sheet with `@media` at-rules inside.

Comment: Test this on a Motorola Moto X2 (on chrome and firefox) with exactly the same result. There is also no different if its landscape or potrait mode (width threshold is in every case 980px). Also interesting is that the Google Mobile test side https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ response exactly the same result too. May be on Android 5.x the threshold is in every case 980pixels ...

Comment: Hi Sime! Found it! I **must** add `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to the HTML. And then your rule seems to be right. See also at the answer of "sharklasers". Thanks.

Comment: @Steffen Ah yes, the meta viewport tag. I always include it by default, so I forgot that it affects how media queries work. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly query physical size.

You can, however, perform a media-type query for DPI along with Height and Width.

Example

```
@media(resolution: 326dpi) and (device-width: 640) and (device-height: 1136) {
   // Iphone 5s
}
```

This should be a good starting point: [List of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density)

Comment: I should create and maintain a list of all mobile devices to do that? Should that be so?? No general solution to detect mobile devices with small screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Physical pixels and CSS pixels are not the the same on retina/HD mobile displays.

Research the viewport meta tag for information on device-width. i.e. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` is the CSS pixel width scaled at 100%.

See [Viewport Device-Widths](http://www.canbike.ca/CSSpixels/) for a list of common mobile screen sizes.

Comment: This together with the answer of "Šime Vidas" seems ok for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing responsive design, you don't actually "detect" the screen size, rather you "target" various size using CSS Media Queries.

If you are using a library like Modernizer for example, that's when you are actually doing detection for various properties.